# Why we name one side as the perpendicular of an angle but does not actually define it?

Tags: geometry, terminology, triangles, angle

If I have a right angled triange:
$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$
[image]
I was wondering why we name the sides like this? The base of $A$ kind of make sense. But the perpendicular of $A$ what relation does it have with the angle $A$? It doesn't even define the angle $A$. Why are we using this terminology? And not use e.g. perpendicular of base of $A$? Or this is what we mean? Because it seems confusing to me.

Comment: I've never seen the sides of a right triangle labelled that way (well OK, I've seen the name "base" before, but that just refers to whichever side is on bottom when you draw it).  I always label them the "opposite" and "adjacent" sides, respectively.  That makes remembering [SOH-CAH-TOA](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SOHCAHTOA.html) really easy.

Comment: @Bye_World:E.g. http://www.freeganita.com/en/trig/8_1.htm

Comment: Well, it _is_ perpendicular to the base of $A$, maybe someone thought saying "perpendicular to the base of $A$" was too long, and shortened it to "perpendicular of $A$"?